# Formatting gtsummary tables with checkbox questions

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

I have been enjoying the `gtsummary` library quite a bit but I can't find a clean way to display checkbox style questions (select all that apply) `gtsummary::tbl_summary`. Here is an example:

```
example_df = tibble::tibble(
  CHOICE1 = sample(c(1, NA), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  CHOICE2 = sample(c(1, NA), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  CHOICE3 = sample(c(1, NA), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)

for(i in 1:3){
  expss::val_lab(example_df[[i]]) = set_names(1, letters[i])
  expss::var_lab(example_df[[i]]) = 'Question 1'
}

example_df %>% 
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    type = list(
      CHOICE1 ~ "categorical",
      CHOICE2 ~ "categorical",
      CHOICE3 ~ "categorical"
    )
  )
```

Ideally, we would just have one header that says 'Question 1' and then each of the columns would be summarized below it. Any suggestions on how to do this properly or gerry rig it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question. Below is an, admittedly, not great solution to your question. But it does get the job done. If you file an GH issue on the gtsummary page, requesting better support for these types of data, we can work together a more concise solution. Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

example_df = tibble::tibble(
  CHOICE1 = sample(c(1, NA), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  CHOICE2 = sample(c(1, NA), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
  CHOICE3 = sample(c(1, NA), size = 10, replace = TRUE)
)

for(i in 1:3){
  expss::val_lab(example_df[[i]]) = setNames(1, letters[i])
  expss::var_lab(example_df[[i]]) = 'Question 1'
}

example_df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., 0L))) %>%
  gtsummary::tbl_summary(
    type = list(
      CHOICE1 ~ "categorical",
      CHOICE2 ~ "categorical",
      CHOICE3 ~ "categorical"
    )
  ) %>%
  remove_row_type(variables = c(CHOICE2, CHOICE3), type = "header") %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      filter(label != "0")
  ) %>%
  as_kable() # converting to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 10** |
| --- | --- |
| Question 1 |  |
| a | 4 (40%) |
| b | 3 (30%) |
| c | 4 (40%) |

<sup>Created on 2022-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! This isn't perfect but I think it gives me enough to go on for my use case.

I imagine this not an uncommon problem (especially in social science) so I'll consider submitting an issue.